# Starting R statet in Mac Os

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-lion, statet

My Operating System is Mac OS Lion

When i start R in eclipse (after successfully installing statet, and in R and bash the packages "rjava, rj and rj-gd") i still get the error message in the picture.[image: error]

in ecipse.ini i have specifed a vm i.e.e

```
-vm
/usr/bin/java
```

The the error log has the following lines. Any help will be appreciated

```
Launching the R Console was cancelled, because it seems starting the R engine failed. 
Please make sure that R package 'rj' (0.5.5 or compatible) is installed and that the R library paths are set correctly for the R environment configuration 'R'.
Process Error Log:
Nov 17, 2011 4:26:41 PM de.walware.rj.server.RMIServerControl start
INFO: [Control:rjs-local-1321543599373] initialize server...
Nov 17, 2011 4:26:41 PM de.walware.rj.server.srvImpl.AbstractServerControl initREngine
SEVERE: [Control:rjs-local-1321543599373] init JRI/Rengine failed.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/walware/rj/server/dbg/TracepointListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at de.walware.rj.server.jri.loader.JRIClassLoader.findClass(JRIClassLoader.java:514)
    at de.walware.rj.server.jri.loader.JRIClassLoader.loadRJavaClass(JRIClassLoader.java:746)
    at de.walware.rj.server.jri.loader.JRIServerLoader.loadServer(JRIServerLoader.java:82)
    at de.walware.rj.server.srvImpl.AbstractServerControl.initREngine(AbstractServerControl.java:145)
    at de.walware.rj.server.RMIServerControl.start(RMIServerControl.java:104)
    at de.walware.rj.server.RMIServerControl.main(RMIServerControl.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.walware.rj.server.dbg.TracepointListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at de.walware.rj.server.jri.loader.JRIClassLoader.findClass(JRIClassLoader.java:514)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Has any of the answers resolved your issue? If so, feel free to check the correct answer as such.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple solution for the issue. I encountered it after updating the StatET plugin.

The StatET IDE changed a lot, and it requires a new version of the RJ library (see section [Installation of the R Packages of RJ](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet)).

In order to install RJ 1.0 (StatET 2.0.x), type the following command:

```
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.0")
```

And the R console is going to work again.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem after an security update of OS X, I tried around and want to show you my "solution". I was reinstalling everything, perhaps this is not needed, but it works.

I reinstalled, cause I thought it is a Java 1.6.0_29 problem, and on OS X I don't now how to downgrade the java installation. See [here](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2011-October/001033.html)

Remove old R and install the newest Version 2.14 (rj 0.5 does not exist for R version 2.14)

```
rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app
wget http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-2.14.0.pkg
[run installer]
r
> install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.0")
[...]
```

I also reinstalled Eclipse and updated it to Version 3.7.1
Add plugins (Help -> Install new Software -> URL from StatET for Eclipse 3.7)

And now some Eclipse configuration in the Run Configuration:

- I used the "Workspace default JRE (JVM 1.5.0)", this is probably not so important

The probably most important configuration (so it was for me) is the path of the R library. If you are not logged in as admin (or have admin rights) the jr library gets written into you home directory: ~/Library/R/2.14/library. You have to add this directory in your R configuration (Eclipse -> Preferences -> StatET -> Run/Debug -> R Environment -> Edit)

Image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/extSz.png) (as unregistered User I am not allowed to integrate images)

This worked for me and everything seems to be fine until now.

About my configuration:

> - OS X 10.6.8
> - Eclipse 3.7.1
>
>   - StatET 1.0.0
> - Java 10.6.0_29 (java -version)
> - R 2.14
>
>   - rj_1.0.2-5
>   - rj.gd_1.0.2-2